# Error when converting to BigQuery timestamp from ISO 8601 date string

Tags: java, date, datetime, google-bigquery, iso8601

I have an ISO 8601 date string in the following format:

```
String myIsoDateString = "2019-02-27T23:00:00.000Z"
```

I need to use the date string as part of a query I'm running in BigQuery. I'm trying to use the `com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryParameterValue` class to convert it to a `QueryParameterValue`, with a type of `timestamp`, like this:

```
QueryParameterValue.timestamp(myIsoDateString)
```

This gives me an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2019-02-27T23:00:00.000Z" is malformed at "T23:00:00.000Z"
```

The inline help in Eclipse for the timestamp method states that it:

```
Creates a QueryParameterValue object with a type of TIMESTAMP. Must be in the format"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ", e.g. "2014-08-19 12:41:35.220000+00:00".
```

How do I convert `myIsoDateString` to the required format? Is there a better method I can use that will handle converting from an ISO 8601 string to a timestamp in BigQuery?

Comment: Substitute the `T` with a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
```

Convert `myIsoDateString` to microseconds and store it as a `long`:

```
long myDateInMicroseconds = DateTime.parse(myIsoDateString).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis() * 1000;
```

Then pass it as the argument to QueryParameterValue.timestamp:

```
QueryParameterValue.timestamp(myDateInMicroseconds)
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying the solution you found. I’d probably prefer the more explicative (but also longer) `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMicros(milliSecondValue)`. Which in turn still loses the microsecond precision from the string (had it had microsecond precision). The perfect conversion exists, but would be still a bit longer.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes - I've updated the answer to show this, thanks. If you edit your answer a bit more to remove the initial assumption about milliseconds, I can mark it as the answer (I don't mind you borrowing on my solution, as long as there's a good and complete answer to the question :)

Comment: Thanks. Chris, that’s kind. I think you should accept your own answer as being most helpful to solve your own problem. In any case you are correct, there was nothing helpful about my wrong guess, so I have taken it out of my answer.

Answer (score 22):

To anyone who is just trying to parse ISO 8601 in BigQuery (this post is the first Google result), try this:

```
SELECT
PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ',  '2018-10-12T13:22:27.120Z')
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be on Documentation page!

Comment: Agreed on having this in the doc. If anyone else wants to throw some feedback on this page, together, we can achieve more :D
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#supported_format_elements_for_datetime

Comment: Although not what the OP asked, if you don't have the Z part, try this:
`SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S', '2022-11-27T00:18:13.081185') `

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the answer the answer by Felipe Hoffa to work and give you what you want: replace the `T` with a space. Here are a couple of other suggestions.

**Be explicit:** While the documentation gives a quite clear example of an expected string, it’s not clear from the error message nor from the documentation (link below, but you’ve got it in Eclipse already) whether `QueryParameterValue.timestamp` accepts the `Z` as an offset. If we want to be sure and also be more explicit about supplying the format asked for (always nice for those managing your code after you):

```
    DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxx");
    String myIsoDateString = "2019-02-27T23:00:00.000Z";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(myIsoDateString);
    QueryParameterValue.timestamp(dateTime.format(timestampFormatter));
```

This passes the string `2019-02-27 23:00:00.000000+00:00` to `timestamp`.

**Pass a long:** `timestamp` comes in an overloaded version taking a `Long` argument. Again it’s not documented what the long value should be. Edit: Your own answer revealed that `timestamp(Long)` requires microseconds since the epoch. The fully correct way to convert without any risk of unnecessary loss of precision is:

```
    String myIsoDateString = "2019-02-27T23:00:00.000Z";
    Instant dateTime = Instant.parse(myIsoDateString);
    long microsecondsSinceEpoch = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(dateTime.getEpochSecond())
            + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(dateTime.getNano());
    QueryParameterValue.timestamp(microsecondsSinceEpoch);
```

A value of 1 551 308 400 000 000 is passed to `timestamp`.

**Disclaimer:** I’m not a BigQuery user.

### Links

- [`QueryParameterValue` documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/QueryParameterValue.html)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: Thanks @Ole V.V. I found that it's microseconds since the epoch that needs to be passed if a `long` is being passed - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

The error says this is not the right format:

```
 "2019-02-27T23:00:00.000Z"
```

But this one would be:

```
 "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ"
```

Try replacing the `T` between date and time with a .

Answer (score 1):

## ISO 8601 versus SQL

The [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard uses a `T` in the middle to separate the year-month-day portion from the hour-minute-second portion.

The [SQL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) style uses a SPACE in the middle rather than a `T`.

Replace.

```
String input = "2019-02-27T23:00:00.000Z".replace( "T" , " " ) ;
QueryParameterValue.timestamp( input ) ;
```

Ditto for going the other direction. The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
String input = "2019-02-27 23:00:00.000Z".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having problems figuring it out for the format:

```
2023-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

I used this method to parse the string (according with these [options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time)):

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%R:%E3S%Ez', '2023-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00')
```